# Visual Studio 17 - Compilation error on non-existent file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm following a tutorial to create an ASP.NET core Web App

I got to a step where I added validation annotations to my Model class

VS17 now complains of compilation errors in a bunch of files that depend on the Model class - e.g. Create.g.cshtml.cs

I tried to look up this file in the `Solution Explorer`, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Presumably this is some sort of generated file from `Code First Migrations`?

How do I clear the error?

[image: Visual Studio 17 -]

Comment: First, check to see if you have a tab open for that file. It will still try to compile it if you have the file open. Close it if you find it, and rebuild. Next, try to find the file on disk with Explorer. If a file has been excluded from the solution, it won't show up in Solution Explorer unless you've enabled the `Show All Files` setting. (I don't see this being a problem as I would expect it to not compile it.) Third, try cleaning before rebuilding. Finally, try restarting VS. I've run into annoying problems like this multiple times that have been fixed just by restarting it.

Comment: `Show All Files` reveals the file in: MvcMovie/obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Movies/Create.g.cshtml.cs, and `Clean` removes it, but any subsequent `Build` causes the file to be regenerated and hence the error re-appears

Comment: I found the issue was a missing `namespace` declaration - but what an awful IDE this is